# Change FCurve handles from Python

Tags: python, scripting, animation

I am currently trying to make an import script that generates an animation on a camera. The animation requires that the values for the left and right keyframe handles be set.

I couldn't find a way to set handle values explicitly, so I have tried to use `bpy.ops.graph.select_border` to select the keyframe handle that I want to set and then use `bpy.ops.transform.translate` to set it into place, however when I try to do this from my import operator, I get a RuntimeError saying **context is incorrect**

Does anyone know if the x and y handle values for an FCurve keyframe can be set from Python?

Comment: Recommend reading the API quickstart - http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/info_quickstart.html#animation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find it here:

```
action=bpy.data.actions['yourAction']
#or
action=bpy.data.objects['yourObject'].animation_data.action
#
action.fcurves[fcurve_index].keyframe_points[kf_index].left_handle
action.fcurves[fcurve_index].keyframe_points[kf_index].right_handle
```

You can easily explore blender's data structures with the outliner using the *datablocks* option and the interactive python console using autocompletion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

If you hover over properties in the editor with python tooltips enabled it often will show you the path to the property.

### Hint:

If the object has not been animated yet and thus `animation_data` is `None`, use the object's method `animation_data_create` to create it.

Afterwards assign an existing action to `animation_data.action` or create a new one:

```
action=bpy.data.actions.new('Your Name')
```

### Note to the developers of blender:

In this case the path shown in the graph editor is abbreviated `bpy.data.objects...left_handle` and it is not possible to right click -> copy data path. So the hint shown is kind of useless.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the keyframe_point collection was marked as read only in the documentation which is why I assumed setting the keyframes from there won't work